# How do I rewrite from useSWRPages to useSWRInfinite?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, swr

I wanted to upgrade from SWR 0.22 to 0.55 but useSWRPages is already deprecated so I would be forced to use useSWRInfinite but I have trouble understanding how to rewrite my current function to use useSWRInfinite. How do I rewrite this to use useSWRInfinite to infinite loading will still be supported?

```
function useRecentDevices(  
  deviceId: string | undefined,
  dateFromUtc: Date | undefined,
  dateToUtc: Date,
) {
  return useSWRPages<Pick<SummaryList, 'skip' | 'take'> | null, SummaryList>(
    'devices',
    ({ offset, withSWR }) => {
      const { data } = withSWR(
        useSWR(
          ['devices/recent', deviceId, offset?.skip, offset?.take ?? DEFAULT_TAKE],
          async (
            path: string,
            deviceId: string | undefined,    
            skip: number | undefined,
            take: number,
          ) => {
            const response = await get<SummaryList>(path, {
              deviceId,
              dateFromUtc: dateFromUtc?.toISOString(),
              dateToUtc: dateToUtc.toISOString(),
              skip,
              take,
            });
            if (!response.success) {
              throw new Error('unable to fetch data');
            }
            return response.data;
          },
          { suspense: !offset },
        ),
      );

      const devices = data?.devices;
      return devices ? devices.map(order => <DeviceLine key={order.salesOrderId} {...order} />) : null;
    },
    ({ data }) => {
      const { hasMore, skip, take } = data!;

      if (hasMore) {
        return { skip: skip + take, take };
      }

      return null;
    },
    [deviceId, dateFromUtc, dateToUtc],
  );
}
```